# Does "ever-booming" make sense?

Tags: word-choice

I would like to express something that keeps booming (technology), and I came up with "ever-booming" which I have never seen it in particular.

I know there are similar words such as everlasting, ever-growing. But can I also say ever-booming, or are there better choices in this case? Thanks!

Comment: It only makes sense until the boom stops.  Which it always does.

Comment: Neologisms will always find detractors. It's really a matter of coining something that is apt to the situation. I am in tech publishing, and while I don't remember ever seeing this term, it is typical of the kind of language writers use to appeal to a mass readership. It's thought of as catchy, and hip. Tech is, after all, dominated by post-Boomers, and the language will change accordingly.

Comment: (The point of my comment above is that any halfway-perceptive reader will know that "booms" never last and will discard as pure marketing babble anything containing a term such as "ever-booming".)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider "never-ending", "unceasing", "eternal", or "perpetual" as possible alternatives.

Comment: Or maybe perpetually booming...

Comment: Thanks, but are there any better alternatives to describe technology?

Comment: You could mention Moore's law? It really depends on what you need it for. Ie: if it is for a formal paper, then you may reconsider using anything not inside a dictionary, but if it is for something like an advertisement, feel free to invent any word you feel fitting. Hope this helps.